# bing web search Api phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bing-api

I am really new to this. Reading from here and there I tried to write some code using the bing search API but nothing seems to happen.

```
  var appid = "API KEY";

function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
}

function deviceready() {
console.log('loaded');

$("#searchButton").bind("touchstart",function() {
    var s = $.trim($("#searchField").val());
    console.log("going to search for "+s);

    $.getJSON("http://api.bing.net/json.aspx?Appid="+appid+"&query="+escape(s)+"&sources=image&image.count=20&Market=%27ar-XA%27&Latitude=11.111&Longitude=11.1111&$top=50", {}, function(res) {
        var results = res.SearchResponse.image.Results;
        if(results.length == 0) {
            $("#results").html("No results!");
            return;
        }
        var s = "";
        for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            s+= "<p>"+results[i].Title+"<br/><a href='"+results[i].Url+"'>"+results[i].DisplayUrl+"</a></p>";                
        }
        $("#results").html(s);
    });

});
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated. I have been pulling my hair out.

Please experts out there any help...

Answer (score 1):

The bing api has been changed around and is now under the windows azure data market. http://api.bing.net will no longer work. [check out their migration guide here  (.docx format)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248077)

Personally, I'm having trouble migrating as there isn't much info written up on the process plus they are now charging bullshit amounts of money for the usage of their API, which I need to use to develop with. It's thrown my app that I was building straight out the window. Just another reason why I hate Microsoft the monetizing bastards.
I wish they could of not done that so I wouldn't have bothered with their API in the first place. It's also funny that they can crawl websites to obtain data and then sell it off like this at their free will.